# Why must the transpose value of glUniformMatrix4fv in webgl/OpenGL ES be false?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

Why must the transpose value of glUniformMatrix4fv in webgl/OpenGL ES be false?

[The OpenGL ES spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) says that the transpose value must be false or an INVALID_VALUE is generated. Why then have the parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter exists because the OpenGL ES spec conforms to the OpenGL spec :
[OpenGL ES 2.0 is defined relative to the OpenGL 2.0 specification](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/)

In the OpenGL spec, this parameter [exists](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) hence it also exists in the OpenGL ES spec, even if it is unused.

Answer (score 11):

Because OES is a subset of standard OpenGL, and the functions must have the same parameters in both implementations. In OpenGL the parameter *transpose* is used to specify if the matrix is in row-major or column-major order, but since OES only supports column-major, it must be always false.

Comment: Note that OpenGL ES is not a _strict_ subset of desktop GL. While both have a function call glTexImage2D, the parameters they take (particularly the pixel format) are very different. Values that are legal in ES are illegal in desktop GL, and vice-versa.